# Typescript Record<Key, object> where object "id" property equals Key

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to make a Record of this shape where the `id` property equals the key of each object entry:

```
{
  id_1: {
     id: 'id_1',
     date: 1234
     comment: 'blah'
  },
  id_2: {
     id: 'id_2',
     date: 5678,
     comment: 'boo'
  }
}
```

Here's what I've come up with so far:

```
export type TMap<T extends string> = {
  [P in T]: { _id: P; date: number; comment: string };
};
```

However, when I use it I need to pass in a paremeter like this:

```
const myMap: TMap<string> = {...}
```

Is the a simpler way to achieve a record where the key is equal to one of the value's properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specify string as the default type of your `TMap`:

```
export type TMap<T extends string = string> = {
  [P in T]: { id: P; date: number; comment: string };
};
```

Then you could use it like so:

```
const myMap: TMap = { ... }
```

## Edit

As @jsejcksn correctly points out, the `TMap` type is incorrect.
It doesn't guarantee that the id will match the key.
When I wrote this answer, I was only looking at making the type more user-friendly, but failed to notice that it was incorrect.

Comment: I don't think this fulfills the requirements in @MarksCode question. It will allow any string for the property key and value of `id` (even if they aren't equal) as long as they are both strings. See [this TS playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NVggnm) for an example.

Comment: @jsejcksn is correct.
I hadn't payed attention to this, as I didn't modify the initial construct from the question, which doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if it's possible to get the compiler to infer what you want using just an annotation without generics, but you could use a functional approach:

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABANwIYBsYBMCyqAOiAPACqICmAHlOWFgM6IDeAUIogNoDSiMSA1uQCecYIhIBdAFyIeVGnUb0oAJz4BzRAH5mbdrywyuAbj3ssqGjLAgAtgCNyK0-sQQ4t27SgzlasOouiAC+iNbkyE6mwQB8iAAUaOgg5DIkAJRpuuwq5FAgKkhJKdEsLO5gyoi2BACMiAC8KBjYePjxrOyoMp362DIA5KgDADRmiBZWiLVjru6e3oMAFuTo6HCjesGziPY94-2IA-abrpOpiABMO+zzXmA+RwDucCroWKchY8HppuUIVRq+EujWamFwBA6em62T6hiOwxuE0sFxm4zuiyOKzWGx22z0e1h7EOQ02AHoyewAHpUlgU8RCfDkI4AIlQLIGvEYYDgUEQqHo9Bg6jAqHs6GZUDgiCgjOZAxZ9g5ADp4pcAMyXS7pcbnGRouYee6PAbY9affE-UxAA)

```ts
function validMap <T extends {
  [K in keyof T]: K extends string ? {
    id: K;
    date: number;
    comment: string;
  } : never;
}> (value: T): T {
  return value;
}

const map1 = validMap({
  a: {
    id: 'a',
    date: 1,
    comment: 'hello',
  },
  b: {
    id: 'b',
    date: 2,
    comment: 'world',
  },
});

const map2 = validMap({
  a: {
    id: 'a',
    date: 1,
    comment: 'hello',
  },
  b: {
    id: 'a',
//  ^^
// Type '"a"' is not assignable to type '"b"'.(2322)
    date: 1,
    comment: 'hello',
  },
});
```